# Make font-size smaller

Tags: fontsize, document-classes, thesis

I've this heading in the first tex file - for a computer science thesis:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref} %per l'indice interattivo
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}    % utilizzato per far riferimento ad un'immagine, e non al suo caption
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\newcommand{\fncyblank }{\fancyhf{}}
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\fncyblank\null \vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries \abstractname \end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
```

and I would make the font-size smaller (10pt to 9pt).
Due to the 9pt size, I've to use `extbook` document class. The problem is that the difference between 10pt and 9pt is too big. 
How could I make the font-size a bit smaller?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use a font that also has intermediate font sizes (e.g. `\usepackage{lmodern}`), you could do something like `\fontsize{9.5pt}{11pt}\selectfont text`

Comment: Normal LaTeX font sizes (\normalsize, \small, \footnotesize...) have a roughtly 1.2  (or .8333 decreasing) scale factor between successive sizes.

Comment: The solution has generated the same result as the `extbook` with 9pt solution.